# Transform(many row -> one row) dataframe as variables (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, one-hot-encoding

I have dataframe which has many rows.

[image]

How can I make this upper dataframe as below which has one rows.
[image]

```
import pandas as pd 

# source dataframe
df_source = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['A01', 'A01'],
    'Code': ['101', '102'],
    'amount for code': [10000, 20000],
    'count for code': [4, 3]
})

# target dataframe
df_target = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['A01'],
    'Code101': [1],
    'Code102': [1],
    'Code103': [0],
    'amount for code101': [10000],
    'count for code101': [4],
    'amount for code102': [20000],
    'count for code102': [3],
    'amount for code103': [None],
    'count for code103': [None],
    'count for code': [None],
    'sum of amount': [30000],
    'sum of count': [7]
})
```

I tried to use method 'get.dummies' but It can be used only for there was that code or not.

How can I handle dataframe to make my dataset?

Comment: Added code for your dataframes. Please check the structure.

Comment: Do you only have codes 101,102,103?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the rows of your existing dataframe and populate (using .at or .loc) your new dataframe (df2). df2 will have the index ID, which is now unique.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['A01', 'A01'],
    'Code': ['101', '102'],
    'amount for code': [10000, 20000],
    'count for code': [4, 3]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns: 
        if col !='ID' and col !='Code': 
                    df2.at[row['ID'],col+row['Code']]=row[col]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot_table:

```
df_result = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Code', values=['amount for code', 'amount for code'])
```

This will return a data frame with multi-level column index, for example `('101', 'amount for code')`
Then you can add other calculated columns like sum of amount and so on.